# Distribution function derivative bounds give bounds on associated measures? Billingsley theorem 31.4 proof.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am working through Billingsley, Probability & Measure.  Struggling with the proof of theorem 31.4:

Suppose $u(a,b) = F(b) - F(a)$ and that $F'$ exists throughout a Borel set $A$.  If $F' ≤ c$ on $A$, then $u(A) ≤ c m(A)$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

2. Why isn't the proposed intersection empty, and why does it increase to $A$?  (Paragraph above eq. 31.19)
3. Why is 3.19 satisfied by the $n_k$ covering intervals?  (Paragraph below 31.20)

Note that pdf copies of this section of the book (31) are readily available online.

Alternatively, I would just love a sketch of the proof that disregards his method (hence no need to address these specific questions, just the theorem itself).

Thanks!

-AJ

Answer (score 0):

https://www.jyotirmoy.net/posts/2014-06-18-errata-billingsley.html

There is, in fact, an error in the definition of the intersections An proposed in both the 3rd and anniversary edition of the book.  See the post linked above for more details (I am not sure the counterexample in the link applies in the situation in discussion in Billingsley preceding the statement of the theorem, but the proposed correction none the less seems to allow the proof to carry through).